# What is the purpose for using OPTION(MAXDOP 1) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have never clearly understood the usage of `MAXDOP`. I do know that it makes the query faster and that it is the last item that I can use for Query Optimization.

However, my question is, when and where it is best suited to use in a query?

Comment: You should include the version and service pack of SQL server. This may have been fixed in a later version ...

Answer (score 39):

As Kaboing mentioned, `MAXDOP(n)` actually controls the number of CPU cores that are being used in the query processor.

On a completely idle system, SQL Server will attempt to pull the tables into memory as quickly as possible and join between them in memory.  It could be that, in your case, it's best to do this with a single CPU.  This might have the same effect as using `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` which forces the query optimizer to use the order of joins that you have specified.  IN some cases, I have seen `OPTION (FORCE PLAN)` reduce a query from 26 seconds to 1 second of execution time.

Books Online goes on to say that possible values for `MAXDOP` are:

> 0 - Uses the actual number of available CPUs depending on the current system workload. This is the default value and recommended setting.
>
> 1 - Suppresses parallel plan generation. The operation will be executed serially.
>
> 2-64 - Limits the number of processors to the specified value. Fewer processors may be used depending on the current workload. If a value larger than the number of available CPUs is specified, the actual number of available CPUs is used.

I'm not sure what the best usage of `MAXDOP` is, however I would take a guess and say that if you have a table with 8 partitions on it, you would want to specify `MAXDOP(8)` due to I/O limitations, but I could be wrong.

Here are a few quick links I found about `MAXDOP`:

[Books Online: Degree of Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188611.aspx)

[General guidelines to use to configure the MAXDOP option](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329204)

Answer (score 19):

This is a general rambling on Parallelism in SQL Server, it might not answer your question directly.

From Books Online, on MAXDOP:

> Sets the maximum number of processors
>   the query processor can use to execute
>   a single index statement. Fewer
>   processors may be used depending on
>   the current system workload.

See [Rickie Lee's blog](http://www.cnblogs.com/rickie/archive/2008/03/18/1111965.html) on parallelism and CXPACKET wait type. It's quite interesting.

Generally, in an OLTP database, my opinion is that if a query is so costly it needs to be executed on several processors, the query needs to be re-written into something more efficient.

Why you get better results adding MAXDOP(1)? Hard to tell without the actual execution plans, but it might be so simple as that the execution plan is totally different that without the OPTION, for instance using a different index (or more likely) JOINing differently, using MERGE or HASH joins.

Answer (score 8):

As something of an aside, MAXDOP can apparently be used as a workaround to a potentially nasty bug:

[Returned identity values not always correct](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/scope-identity-sometimes-returns-incorrect-value#)

Comment: link is down - [mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20130412223343/https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/scope-identity-sometimes-returns-incorrect-value)

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of parallization bugs in SQL server with abnormal input. OPTION(MAXDOP 1) will sidestep them.

EDIT: Old. My testing was done largely on SQL 2005. Most of these seem to not exist anymore, but every once in awhile we question the assumption when SQL 2014 does something dumb and we go back to the old way and it works. We never managed to demonstrate that it wasn't just a bad plan generation on more recent cases though since SQL server can be relied on to get the old way right in newer versions. Since all cases were IO bound queries MAXDOP 1 doesn't hurt.

Comment: Could you elaborate on those bugs please?

Comment: I was unable to fully qualify the bugs, but one in particular: when a left join was expected to match very few % of rows would try to spool both tables and loop join rather than bookmark lookup only with parallelization on.

Comment: @Joshua, Do you know if the bugs are still relevant to SQL 2012, 14 or 16 versions?

Comment: @HappyTown I would expect that the bugs will have disappeared or, at the very least, have changed. There have been substantial changes in the query optimizer with every major version of SQL Server. In addition, SQL Server 2014 received a new cardinality estimator (which also saw dramatic improvements in 2016). 

It's also not entirely fair to call them bugs as it doesn't sound like query results were changed - they may be optimization bugs, but they're not bugs in the sense that your results will be bad.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my two cents, based on a performance issue I observed.

If simple queries are getting parellelized unnecessarily, it can bring more problems than solving one. However, before adding MAXDOP into the query as "knee-jerk" fix, there are some server settings to check.

In [Jeremiah Peschka - Five SQL Server Settings to Change](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/09/five-sql-server-settings-to-change/), MAXDOP and "COST THRESHOLD FOR PARALLELISM" (`CTFP`) are mentioned as important settings to check.

Note: Paul White mentioned `max server memory` aslo as a setting to check, in a response to [Performance problem after migration from SQL Server 2005 to 2012](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115228/performance-problem-after-migration-from-sql-server-2005-to-2012?rq=1). A good kb article to read is [Using large amounts of memory can result in an inefficient plan in SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2413549)

[Jonathan Kehayias - Tuning ‘cost threshold for parallelism’ from the Plan Cache](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/tuning-cost-threshold-for-parallelism-from-the-plan-cache/) helps to find out good value for `CTFP`.

[Why is cost threshold for parallelism ignored?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81980/why-is-cost-threshold-for-parallelism-ignored)

[Aaron Bertrand - Six reasons you should be nervous about parallelism](https://sqlblog.org/2009/03/21/six-reasons-you-should-be-nervous-about-parallelism) has a discussion about some scenario where MAXDOP is the solution.

Parallelism-Inhibiting Components are mentioned in [Paul White - Forcing a Parallel Query Execution Plan](http://web.archive.org/web/20180404164406/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/23/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.aspx)