# Does setting MaxDOP on Database level restrict CPUs for that DB or for Queries ran in that DB?

Tags: sql, sql-optimization

We have a CPU with 16 cores.  The CPU is used only for SQL server with a single database.  Currently, MaxDOP is set to 0.

We were considering changing the MAXDOP to 8 in an attempt to limit the max number of CPU's used by a query, however a consultant DBA is stating that this will limit the number of CPU's used by the database.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the server level = all queries. This is the [max degree of parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181007%28SQL.105%29.aspx) option

Per query, use the [MAXDOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163917/optionmaxdop-1-in-sql-server) hint

Comment: Answered my basic question, any chance you can offer some detail on weather setting to 8 might help/hurt us over our current setting of 0?

Comment: @JeremyWest: TPersonally, I'd try to tune offending queries first, then add MAXDOP hint in specific cases. I wouldn't normally set it at the server level. In fact, I never have

Comment: +1 - Not what I wanted to hear, but that is the advise I was looking for.  I was under the impression that there was some recommended setting I should start at.  I will consider implementing on a query by query basis.

Answer (score 1):

You can always specify "OPTION (MAXDOP 1)" at the end of the query you want to limit. This will only affect that query.